# How to know when AngularJS digest cycle ends without using $timeout?

Tags: angularjs, timeout, lifecycle, angularjs-digest

This is a general question about AngularJS.

AngularJS does not raise an event to notify when the digest cycle has ended. AngularJS suggests using `$timeout` as a solution to queue your work to be run after the current digest cycle (also waits for DOM rendering to be completed by the browser).

Does anyone know how to know if `$scope.$apply()` and `$scope.$digest()` have ended without using `$timeout`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.$digest()`, before your business logic function or `$scope.$apply(function(){/*your business*/})` but this method like timeout function.